# iOS How to align UIViews / UILabels along a angled axis?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to setup a series of UILabels that have their X-centers aligned along a 45degree angel.

I imagine I can do this mathematically, but is there a way I can draw a 45degree line and then assign each UILabel to be positioned at different points along that 45degree line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a constraint for your label's center-x, center-y to be a percentage of the containing view's width / height.  Here's a quick example in the context of a generic view controller:

```
for ( CGFloat m = 0.25 ; m < 1 ; m += .25 ) {

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
    label.text = @"Hello, World";
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview: label];


    NSLayoutConstraint* lcx = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: label
                                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem: self.view
                                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          multiplier: m
                                                            constant: 0];

    NSLayoutConstraint* lcy = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: label
                                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem: self.view
                                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          multiplier: m
                                                            constant: 0];

    [self.view addConstraint: lcx];
    [self.view addConstraint: lcy];
}
```